# How to "like" query Mongo for databases

Tags: regex, mongodb

I have a database that is being created through an external script. The database is named based on the run. So it follows the format "name_variable" where "name_" is constant. I'm trying to switch to the database in mongo after it is created, but I couldn't find a way to "like" query for databases.

I tried something like:

```
conn = new Mongo();
db = conn.getDB({name: {$regex: /name_$/}}));
print(db);
```

That didn't work. My question is, is there a way to find databases who's names are like a regex statement.

Thanks.

Comment: Like means a string equals a pattern, right? Use `/^name_.*$/` to match all strings that start with `name_` and then can have 0+ chars.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes I did mean matching string equals pattern. The syntax isn't my concern. I'm just wondering if Mongo has a function that can query for databases something similar to db.collections.find but on the database level.